# Retrieving multiple images from database to a dynamically loading image control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ado.net

In my project I have a dynamically loading image control to display the `names & photos` of the members of that website.

For retrieving images I used an image `handler`, but the problem is that in the search box code I used a like search so that the similar names can be displayed dynamically loading image control will display all the name but the image will be the same for all image controls, if we specifically tell the name it will display the correct image, how  can I overcome this problem?

Code of the handler is below:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
string s2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["firstname"];
string sql = "SELECT UploadPhoto FROM profiledata  where firstname='" + s2 + "'";
```

In the cs file, code is like this(dynamically loading image control page):

```
string s2 = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
i2.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage2.ashx?firstname=" + s2;
```

Comment: As always: Please pay attention to [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png).

Comment: To enhance security, use AntiXSS library to filter your input and outputs for use with SQL queries. More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx